# Error 500 with my DELETE Endpoint: REST API NESTJS

Tags: rest, nestjs, crud, http-status-code-500, http-delete

I'm trying to implement a basic CRUD API with NestJS.
I simulate userbase management.
I tried to catch the errors, and handle the edge cases.

But with my delete endpoint, I got this response when trying to delete:

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

but the user has been deleted.

and in Nestjs:

```
[Nest] 4792  - 22/02/2023 15:30:56   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
```

here is my controller:

```
@Delete(':id')
  async remove(@Param(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true })) { id }: IdDto) {
    try {
      const userDeleted = await this.userService.delete(id);
      return response.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({
        message: 'User has been successfully deleted',
        userDeleted,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof NotFoundException) {
        return response.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).json({
          message: 'User not found',
        });
      } else {
        return response.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json({
          message: 'We could not retrieve the user',
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

and my service:

```
async delete(id: string): Promise<any> {
    const userToDelete = await this.userModel.findById(id).exec();
    if (userToDelete == null) {
      throw new NotFoundException('user not found');
    }
    return await this.userModel.deleteOne(userToDelete.id);
  }
```

Do you have any advice? Thanks guys !!

EDIT:

For example, when I test ../users/id (GET METHOD) with a valid MongoDB id (but with no user found) , I got this response:

```
{
"statusCode": 500,
"message": "Internal server error"
}
```

and in console:

```
[Nest] 1431  - 23/02/2023 08:49:27   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
    at ServerResponse.json (node_modules/express/lib/response.js:268:20)
    at UsersController.find (src/users/user.controller.ts:51:54)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at /node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:46:28
    at node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:9:17
```

it's the same response when I delete , but it deletes.

Comment: does that `.get` call was made in your side? check out the first line of the stack trace

Comment: I just do ../users/id on postman with delete method

Comment: right, but you don't have the full code so we don't know how's calling that `foo.get` method (`foo` is `undefined`, in your case). Just show us the stack trace, please.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved by editing to this:

```
@Get(':id')
  async find(@Param(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true })) { id }: IdDto) {
    try {
      const user = await this.userService.findOne(id);
      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof NotFoundException) {
        throw new HttpException(
          {
            status: HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
            code: 'USER_NOT_FOUND',
            error: 'User not found',
          },
          HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
          {
            cause: error,
          },
        );
      }
      return response.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json({
        code: 'BAD_REQUEST',
        message: 'We could not retrieve the user',
      });
    }
  }
```